# 2 modals opening when using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've got 2 modals in my page. When calling the 2nd modal, both will open. What's wrong?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal Body</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" href="otherpage.php">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" href="otherpage.php">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>      

<div id="modal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal Body</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" href="otherpage.php">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" href="otherpage.php">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm loading bootstrap and i'm using this function to call the 2nd modal

```
$('#modal2').modal('show');
```

when calling this function the first modal will also show up. What's wrong? because I would expect only the 2nd modal to show.

Comment: Based on the code you provided, it appears to work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfram7hd/). Is there any other related code that may be causing this?

Comment: It would be good if you also post on what case you are opening this `modals`

Comment: I'm opening the second modal when a form is submitted. For testing purpose i'm using this command in the Chrome console: $('#modal2').modal('show');

Comment: @JoshCrozier thanks for the tip! There was some other related code in my custom.js which caused this: $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
});    Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been provided by @Josh Crozier.

There was some other dependancy in my code in my custom.js the function below was triggering the other modal. I was not aware of this.

```
$(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Thanks for the help!